# Input redirection to grep

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a directory with contents like this -

```
vishal.yadav@droid36:~/Shell$ ls
lazy_dog.txt  ls-error.txt  ls-output.txt  ShellCommands.txt TheTimeMachineHGWells.txt  words.txt  words.txt.bak
```

---

### First Command

If I try using `ls | grep *.txt` I get the following output -

```
ShellCommands.txt:                      $ cat > lazy_dog.txt
ShellCommands.txt:                      $ cat lazy_dog.txt
ShellCommands.txt:                      $ cat < lazy_dog.txt
ShellCommands.txt:input from the keyboard to the file lazy_dog.txt. We see that the result is the
```

### Second Command

And if I use `ls | grep .*.txt` I get this as output -

```
lazy_dog.txt
ls-error.txt
ls-output.txt
ShellCommands.txt
TheTimeMachineHGWells.txt
words.txt
words.txt.bak
```

---

Isn't `.*.txt` and `*.txt` one and the same?

In the **First Command**, is the output of `ls` the `regex` for `grep` or is it the `list of files`?
Similarly, for the **Second Command**, is the output of `ls` the `regex` or `list of files`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first command (`ls | grep *.txt`), the output from `ls` is completely ignored by `grep` because it sees:

```
grep lazy_dog.txt ls-error.txt ls-output.txt ShellCommands.txt TheTimeMachineHGWells.txt
```

It has one pattern `lazy_dog.txt` and four files, so it reads each file in turn to find the pattern, and prefixes the matching output lines with the name of the file that held the pattern.  If there was only one file name, it would not list the file name before the matched lines.

It appears that the only file of the four that `grep` searches (`ls-error.txt`, `ls-output.txt`, `ShellCommands.txt`, `TheTimeMachineHGWells.txt`) that contains the text `lazy_dog.txt` is `ShellCommands.txt`, so that's what you see in the output.  Note that a line containing `lazy_dogstxt` would also match the regex (but not the shell glob).

In the second command (`ls | grep .*.txt`), there are no files that match `.*.txt`, so that argument is passed to `grep` unexpanded, so it has only a pattern, so it reads its standard input, which is the output from `ls` this time.  All the file names match the regex `.*.txt` (even though none of them match the shell glob `.*.txt`), so they're all listed.  Note that it would also pick up many other lines, even one containing just "etxt", because the `.` is a `grep` metacharacter (and the `.*.txt` regex matches any string of zero or more characters followed by one arbitrary character and then `txt`.

Comment: So `lazy_dog.txt` becomes a `regex`? Also, when does `grep` consider something as a glob (for file matching) or as a regular expression (for string matching)? Isn't globbing done by the shell itself?

Comment: Yes, `lazy_dog.txt` becomes the regex because the usage for `grep` is `grep [options] regex [file ...]`.  There are no options; the first argument (`lazy_dog.txt`) fits the regex position, and the rest of the names become the files.  Yes, the globbing is done by the shell; that's why `grep` sees the list of file names.  If the shell didn't do the globbing, `grep` would just see `*.txt` as the (regex) argument, and since it is then given no file names, it would read standard input, which is the output from `ls`.  The regex `*.txt` requires a literal `*` followed by any character and then `txt`.

Comment: `since it(grep) is then given no file names, it would read standard input, which is the output from ls`. Got it! Your answers are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

do `ls -al`:

you will find that the current directory is listed as a `.` and previous directory is listed as `..`.

So when you say `ls | grep .*.txt`, the `.` is taken as path matching from current directory that contains `.txt` afterwards.

Comment: What happens to the output of `ls`? Is it ignored?

Comment: The explanation about `.` being taken as path is wrong. See the accepted answer for proper details.

Answer (score 0):

grep see the pattern `.*.txt` as regex, not [glob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

So you can use `ls *.txt` or `ls | grep .*txt`

Comment: So for the command `ls | grep *.txt` does `grep` ignore the output of `ls`?

Comment: @yadav_vi what do you mean by ignore?

Comment: Both `grep *.txt` and `ls | grep *.txt` give the same output. That is what I meant by ignore.